# How to add variables to a php form handler from sql table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, variables, post

Hello everybody!

When we insert html form data into an sql table, we have this variable list in the handler document:

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
```

And so on.

Now - I have a sawmill, where lumber with different specifications is being produced. Those specifications are stored in an sql table. I can add new ones by using a html form (for example pine boards 19mm*100mm*3m will create a 'p191003' entry in the table). 
This is then **used as an input field name** in another form, where I have a table with all the sizes and input fields to enter the amounts (number of logs produced). Every day the produced amounts are submitted to another sql table.
My problem is, I need every added size to 'appear' in the variable list to be able to submit the amount produced to the database. 
If I did it manually, it would look like this:

```
$p191003 = $_POST['p191003'];
$p1910024 = $_POST['p1910024'];
$p221003 = $_POST['p221003'];
$p227024 = $_POST['p227024'];
$p22703 = $_POST['p22703'];
$p221453 = $_POST['p221453'];
$p291003 = $_POST['p291003'];
```

EDIT1:

This is how I add the specifications to the database:

```
<form action="proc_spec.php" method="post" />

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:pCheck();" name="type" id="sp" value="Spruce/pine">Spruce/pine
<br>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:pCheck();" name="type" id="bir" value="Birch">Birch
<br>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:pCheck();" name="type" id="asp" value="Aspen">Aspen
<br><br>
<table><tr>
<td>Height (мм):</td><td>Width (мм): </td><td>Length (м): </td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type="height" name="height" /></td><td><input type="width" name="width" /></td><td><input type="length" name="length" /></td>
</tr>
</table>



<br><br><br><br>

<input type="image" src="images/confirm.png" class="pic" alt="Confirm" />
    </form>
```

This is the handler:

```
//connect to db
$type = $_POST['type'];
$height = $_POST['height'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$length = $_POST['length'];


$h = $height * 0.001;
$w = $width * 0.001;
$l = $length;
$v = $h * $w * $l;
$lvar = $length * 10;




 // begin the transaction
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    // our SQL statememtns


    if ($type == 'sp') {
    $conn->exec("INSERT INTO Rspecs (name, volume, type, scode) VALUES ('$h&#215;$w&#215;$l', '$v', '$type', 'sp$height$width$lvar')");
    }

    if ($type == 'bir') {
    $conn->exec("INSERT INTO Rspecs (name, volume, type, scode) VALUES ('$h&#215;$w&#215;$l', '$v', '$type', 'bir$height$width$lvar')");
    }

    if ($type == 'asp') {
    $conn->exec("INSERT INTO Rspecs (name, volume, type, scode) VALUES ('$h&#215;$w&#215;$l', '$v', '$type', 'asp$height$width$lvar')");
    }




 // commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
    echo "Added to database";
    include("views/add_processing.php");
    } //disconnect
```

This is the form to add the produced sizes (php part):

```
//connect


    $query = "SELECT type, name, volume, speccode FROM Rspecs GROUP by type";
    $result = mysql_query($query);


    while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
    {


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['type']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['volume']."</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='amount' name='".$row['scode']."' /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }



    // disconnect from the database
```

And this is the handler I used before (when I had to enter the sizes manually)

```
$p191003 = $_POST['p191003'];
$p1910024 = $_POST['p1910024'];
$p221003 = $_POST['p221003'];
$p227024 = $_POST['p227024'];
$p22703 = $_POST['p22703'];
$p221453 = $_POST['p221453'];
$p291003 = $_POST['p291003'];
$p2910024 = $_POST['p2910024'];
$p291453 = $_POST['p291453'];
$p441003 = $_POST['p441003'];
$p4410024 = $_POST['p4410024'];
$p441453 = $_POST['p441453'];
$b229808 = $_POST['b229808'];
$p2210012 = $_POST['p2210012'];
$p2210024 = $_POST['p2210024'];
$b229824 = $_POST['b229824'];
$b229820 = $_POST['b229820'];
$b229812 = $_POST['b229812'];
$b2214524 = $_POST['b2214524'];





 // begin the transaction
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    // our SQL statememtns




$conn->exec("INSERT INTO Eprocessing (date, amount, product, sort, notes, type, optype) 
    VALUES 

('$date', '$b229824', '22&#215;98&#215;2,4', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$b229820', '22&#215;98&#215;2,0', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$b229812', '22&#215;98&#215;1,2', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$b2214524', '22&#215;145&#215;2,4', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p1910024', '19&#215;100&#215;2,4', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p291003', '29&#215;100&#215;3,0', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p2910024', '29&#215;100&#215;2,4', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p291453', '29&#215;145&#215;3,0', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p441003', '44&#215;100&#215;3,0', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p4410024', '44&#215;100&#215;2,4', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p441453', '44&#215;145&#215;3,0', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$b229808', '22&#215;98&#215;0,8', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p2210012', '22&#215;100&#215;1,2', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p2210024', '22&#215;100&#215;2,4', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p227024', '22&#215;70&#215;2,4', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p22703', '22&#215;70&#215;3,0', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production'),
('$date', '$p221003', '22&#215;100&#215;3,0', '0-2', '$notes', '$type', 'Production')");



$conn->exec("DELETE FROM Eprocessing WHERE amount=0");




 // commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
    echo "Added to database";
    include("views/add_processing.php");
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    // roll back the transaction if something failed
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    } //disconnect
```

Is there a way to load the variables list from the sql database?

Is there perhaps a better solution to my situation?

I hope I made my problem clear, please tell me if not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you've made your problem clear. What you haven't made clear, however, is the code showing what you've attempted so far.

Comment: extract($_POST,EXTR_OVERWRITE); does the same as your **manually** code box

Comment: Thank you very much, everybody! I am glad there was a solution that simple - one command to replace the whole POST list. Now I am going to enter the number of produced boards of each size and send them via POST. Still need to extract the corresponding data from my specs table (there is a coefficient representing the volume of each board size and the name of production, that will appear in the table, these directly depend on one of the variables) and insert it into the production table for each size (if amount entered was larger than 0). Could you help me out with this one too?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but if you want every item in `$_POST` data into separate variable, you can use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
```

`EXTR_SKIP` makes sure that any of existing variables will not be overwritten. This is for security.

Then you have variables `$p191003`, `$p1910024` etc. `$_POST` `array` keys will be variable names.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this...

```
$array = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($array); /* just to see it */
```

Then you could loop through the array to run your queries